# Is it possible to avoid giving labels entirely to a line graph from Chart JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js

I have a Chart JS linegraph that is supposed to take data from a backend and display it on a webpage. However, the chart has nearly 1000 points to plot and not only can i not provide labels for all of them, I cannot fit labels for them on the frontend either. I want to avoid giving the labels attribute entirely. This is what my code looks like right now

```
function Graphs() {
    const data = {
        labels: ['label1', 'label2', 'label3'],//I want to avoid giving this
        datasets: [{
            label: "First dataset",
            backgroundColor: "black",
            data: [1, 2, 3] //One thousand values will be passed here
        }]
    }
    return (
        <div><Line data={data}
        /></div>
    )
```

So far I have tried hiding the x-labels using the options attribute given below.

```
...
    options:{
        scales:{
            x: {
                display: false
            }
        }
    }
```

This did remove the labels on the frontend, but the code still demands that I enter labels in order for it to show data. If I enter 3 labels as above and 4 data points ( data:[1,2,3,4]), it only displays the first 3 points and ignores the rest of the data.
Other than this, I tried passing an empty array (labels: []), completely removing the labels and passing an empty string instead of an array but all three of them do not show any data. If I pass a string, it splices the string and uses its letters as labels.
Is there something in the options attribute that I can use here? If I can somehow display a single label for all 1000 values. That will also work. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, you can provide a label array containing empty strings:

```
labels:Array(3).fill('') // 3 represents the size of the data array
```

In addition, I advise you to take a look at this thread, people proposed different implementation to skip the labels: https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/12